# Blazor application generates wrong MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

My Blazor standalone application .Net 5.0 generates a wrong MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cs with the following content if I add a project reference to it:

```
 [assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartAttribute("Wur.GroupTool.Core")]
```

Giving the following error (note the double 'AttributeAttribute'):

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Wur.GroupTool.Blazor    C:\Projects\FB-IT\grouptool\sources\Wur.GroupTool\Wur.GroupTool.Blazor\obj\Debug\net5.0\Wur.GroupTool.Blazor.MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cs 14  Active
```

My guess is that the attribute shoule be:

```
[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPart("Wur.GroupTool.Core")]
```

but since it is generated I have no clue how to handle this problem. Tried changing the code of course but on compilation it is regenerated again and hence the error again.

== EDIT ==

Just started from scratch again using this command:

```
dotnet --dry-run new blazorwasm -au SingleOrg --framework:net5.0
```

Changed the library to insert to starget net5.0. Issue stays the same. It could be a bug in the compiler. When 'Attribute' is added it should use that name but instead it adds 'Attribute' to the name resulting to 'AttributeAttribute'.

Comment: IMO it's not your issue, `ApplicationPart` and `ApplicationPartAttribute` is the same class `ApplicationPart` is the short notation for `ApplicationPartAttribute` as any attributes in C#.

Comment: Take a closer look. The problem is that it tries to resolve ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute (twice the Attribute name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is as follows. In the Library I wanted to add some MVC libraries were present. Blazor does not like loading MVC libraries, they don't mix well. The error was misleading. But after removing all code that uses MVC from the library (which should not have been in there in the first place) the reference was accepted just fine.